# Display button created by document.createElement on another html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling a JavaScript function from a.html that creates a button..I want that button to be displayed on b.html..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
      btn.appendChild(t);
      document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: both this page include same js file?

Comment: How to you load b.html?

Comment: If your want to create element dynamically to another document. I think you need to use a server side scripting language like php,asp,jsp.

Comment: @brk yes both pages have the same js file...

Comment: @RionWilliams yes they generate the button..but how to generate them in b.html instead of the same html page

Comment: @mplungjan I have a blank b.html if I try to link it to this page it just creates the button on this page and goes to the blank b.html

Comment: I cannot think of a use case where this makes sense. Please explain step for step what you want to happen

Comment: I have a website that has 2 html pages. one is the home page(a.html) that have different buttons.. based on what button you click on a.html,  b.html should display different buttons that have their own different functions...